# Experimenting with vim/gvim in "virgin" mode

Tags: plugin-system, invocation

Sometimes, I would like to try a trick I find in the internet. It is often helpful to try this in vim (gvim if it is a gui trick), in virgin mode, i.e., without loading all my ~/.vimrc stuff.

Do you have any tips for doing this efficiently?

Comment: Your question reminded me of: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gd3oYFS9g9I :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [Vim FAQ 2.5](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5):

> ```
> vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE
> ```
>
> This starts Vim in nocompatible mode (-N), without reading your
>   viminfo file (-i NONE), without reading any configuration file (-u
>   NONE for not reading .vimrc file and -U NONE for not reading a .gvimrc
>   file) or even plugin.

After opening Vim/gVim you can use `:source <path>` to load a test vimrc or plugin.

You could also use `-u NORC` to skip only the vimrc but load the plugins (more details at `:help -u`).

Comment: (Under linux/unix) You can make this less of a mouthful by aliasing it (eg in your bash profile) ... **alias virvim="vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE"** then you can just use virvim from then on :)